# IntelliJ can't associate javadoc and sources for dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

I have noticed that my IntelliJ doesn't properly show javadoc/sources. I have downloaded them thru right click -> maven -> download sources and documentation. When I go to the directory where its supposed to be located, I find everything that I need :

```
xxx-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated
xxx.sources.jar.lastUpdated
```

The issue seems to be .lastUpdated part. When I look at my project dependencies I can see clearly that intelliJ looks for
**xxx-javadoc.jar**
instead of

```
xxx-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated
```

How can I make sure that IntelliJ properly downloads and names javadoc/sources properly? I don't want to manually rename everything and then manually set javadoc/sources through IntelliJ interface.

I think this issue happened when I interrupted the download of sources/documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.lastUpdated` files are **not** the jar fails themselves, but a mechanism that Maven uses to track when it last updated a file. I.e., the file you should load in IntelliJ is the jar file, not the `.lastUpdated` file.

If an interrupted/corrupted update is causing issues, remove that fail along with its `.lastUpdated` file and download (synchronize in IntelliJ) it again.

Comment: Jep, used bat file to remove all of those files automatically and now downloading sources/documentation again. Wont interupt the process again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have searched around and problem was probably caused by interuption of download sources/documentation process. Using bat file :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set last=?
 
for /f %%I in ('dir /s /b /o:n /a-d "*.lastUpdated"') do (
  if !last! NEQ %%~dpI ( 
    set last=%%~dpI
    echo !last!
    rd /s /q !last!
  )
)
goto end
 
:end
```

I managed to remove all the necessary files. Now downloading again. If this happens to you, use the above bat script if you are on windows.